# What download images from remote url

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I've array of url images. I need download asynchronous this images from remote url to my server.

EXAMPLE:

```
// i need this function return array localfiles after download 

function someFunctionAsDownloadedRemoteIMages(arrayOfRemoteUrls){
    localImages = [];
    arrayOfRemoteUrls.forEach(function(url){
        request.head(url, function(err, res, body){
            newImageName = randomInt(100000, 999999);
            var filename = 'catalog/import/'+newImageName+'.jpg';

            request(url, {encoding: 'binary'}, function(error, response, body) {
              fs.writeFile('image/'+filename, body, 'binary', function (err) {
                if(err)
                    return;
                localImages.push(filename);
              });
            });
        });
    });
}

var remoteImagesArray = ["http://example.com/1.jpg", "http://example.com/1444.jpg","http://example.com/ddsgggg.jpg"]; 

localImagesArray = someFunctionAsDownloadedRemoteIMages(remoteImagesArray); 

someFunctionProccess(localImagesArray);
```

Comment: So what’s the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to asynchronously return anything you must use a callback pattern instead of returning a value from a function. With that said you also need a way for the final result callback to fire once all images have been loaded. I would suggest using a module like async and use the `map` function it provides. The `map` function will allow you to process an array and it gives back an array of results. Below is an example:

```
var async = require('async');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');

function processUrl(url, callback){
    request.head(url, function(err, res, body){
            var newImageName = randomInt(100000, 999999);
            var filename = 'catalog/import/'+newImageName+'.jpg';

            request(url, {encoding: 'binary'}, function(error, response, body) {
              fs.writeFile('image/'+filename, body, 'binary', function (err) {
                if(err) return callback(err);
                callback(null,filename);
              });
            });
        });
}

function someFunctionAsDownloadedRemoteIMages(arrayOfRemoteUrls, callback){
    async.map(arrayOfRemoteUrls, processUrl, callback);
}



var remoteImagesArray = ["http://example.com/1.jpg", "http://example.com/1444.jpg","http://example.com/ddsgggg.jpg"]; 

someFunctionAsDownloadedRemoteIMages(remoteImagesArray, function(err, localImagesArray){
    if(err) //handle it
    someFunctionProccess(localImagesArray); 
});
```